# Trying to modify a string via replace function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a little js to modify URLs in browser but it doesn't work when I use two in a row. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I am trying to modify a youtube url to let another site process it.

```
javascript:{
    /* this script doesn't work now, needs more work */
    let myURL = document.URL ;
    let ytURL = "https://ytscribe.com/v/" + myURL.match(/watch.*$/).replace('watch?v=', '') ; 
    console.log(ytURL);
}
```

Here is the error it throws:

```
VM382:4 Uncaught TypeError: myURL.match(...).replace is not a function
    at <anonymous>:4:66
(anonymous) @ VM382:4
```

Comment: That is because [`match(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value) returns an array or `null`

Comment: You can simply use `myURL.replace(/watch.*$/, '')`

Comment: JS has [native support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) for URL parsing. Use `new URL(document.URL).searchParams.get('v')` instead of regex.

Comment: @PoneyUHC [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) works with a regex, and in the case of being given a string, it will convert that string to a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the [replace method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on the result of the [match method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), which returns an array. You need to first access the matched string from the array before using the replace method:

```
let myURL = document.URL;
let match = myURL.match(/watch.*$/);
let ytURL = "https://ytscribe.com/v/" + match[0].replace('watch?v=', '');
console.log(ytURL);
```

The code above will turn `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XKIs1_FpLw` into `https://ytscribe.com/v/3XKIs1_FpLw` when being executed on [this YouTube video page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XKIs1_FpLw).

Comment: Thank you very much, I suppose I can simplify this then and just refer to the matched part by using something like this then?
```
let myURL = document.URL; 
let match = myURL.match(/watch\?v=(.*)$/);
let ytURL = "https://ytscribe.com/v/" + match[1];
console.log(ytURL);
```